# jQuery maintaining state across pages. jQuery cookie plugin?

Tags: jquery, cookies

**background**

i am actually creating an infinite page scroller in jQuery for my tumblr. i want users to be able to disable this functionality. maybe enable it again if they want, thats later.

**problem so far**

i can disable the auto loading of new pages using a link that will `unbind()` the `scroll()` event. also it sets a variable `infiniteScrollingEnabled = false` so that my script will not append loaded data to the page.

```
$("#btnDisable").click(function() {
  $window.unbind("scroll", infiniteScroll);
  $(".loading", postsSelector).fadeOut("slow");
  isLoading = false;
  infiniteScrollEnabled = false;
});
```

but when u user goes to a new page via a link, infinite scrolling is enabled again. to fix this i guess i need cookies.

**solution considered**

jQuery [cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/node/1387)

**question**

how can i find out dynamically what is the domain i shld use? or is there a need to set that option?

Comment: cookies have very limited storage. have you considered [DOM Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage)?

Comment: ignore the domain, you only need it for multi-domain sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the domain of the current page using standard javascript: `window.location.hostname` (or `window.location.host` if you want to include any port that may be specified).